# check to see if all objects in an array has a common property

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which I am trying to loop over and check for a common key if it exists for all objects. if the specific key does not exist for all objects I return false.

Here is my code

```
var x = [{
  "item": "alpha",
  "value": "red"
}, {
  "item": "beta",
  "value": "blue"
}, {
  "item": "beta",
  "value": "gama"
}]

function test(obj) {
  var count = 0;
  var out = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('value')) {
      count = i;
    }
  }
  if (count == obj.length) {
    out = true
  }
}

console.log(test(x))
```

I am getting undefined. Cant figure out what am I missing here

Comment: `test` doesn't return anything (which is equivalent to having `return undefined` as the last statement in a function) - having said that, `count` will at most equal `obj.length - 1` because that's as high as `i` can get ... try `count = count + 1` instead of `count = i`

Comment: Also instead of counting, you could just `return false` the first time `obj[i].hasOwnProperty('value')` is false. No point in continuing through the array once you find one of them doesn't have it

Comment: @JaromandaX -- totally worked. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: The `every` method looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation, which finds *every* matching key, even nested keys, given a set of objects:

```
function recurse_obj(obj, cb, _stack = []) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        cb(k, obj[k], _stack);
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k) && (obj[k] instanceof Object)) {
            _stack.push(k);
            recurse_obj(obj[k], cb, _stack);
            _stack.pop();
        }
    }
}

function obj_all_keys(obj) {
    var tmp = [];

    recurse_obj(obj, (k, v, stack) => {
        var ext = (stack.length) ? "." : ""; 
        tmp.push(stack.join(".").concat(ext, k));
    }); 

    return tmp;
}

function key_intersection(...objs) {
    var lookup = {};

    objs.forEach(o => {
        obj_all_keys(o).forEach(k => {
            if (k in lookup === false)
                lookup[k] = 0;
            lookup[k]++;
        });
    });

    for (var k in lookup)
        if (lookup[k] !== objs.length)
            delete lookup[k];

    return lookup;
}
```

Here is the calling code:

```
var me = { name: { first: "rafael", last: "cepeda" }, age: 23, meta: { nested: { foo: { bar: "hi" } } } };    
console.log(key_intersection(me, { name: { first: "hi" } }));
```

Output: `{ name: 2, 'name.first': 2 }`

The object returned includes only the keys that are found in all the objects, the set intersection, the counts are from book-keeping, and not removed in the callee for performance reasons, callers can do that if need be.

Keys that are included in other *nested* keys could be excluded from the list, because their inclusion is implied, but I left them there for thoroughness.

Passing a collection (array of objects) is trivial:
`key_intersection.apply(this, collection);`

or the es6 syntax:
`key_intersection(...collection);`

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to do this is to use [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this

```js
var x = [{
  "item": "alpha",
  "value": "red"
}, {
  "item": "beta",
  "value": "blue"
}, {
  "item": "beta",
  "value": "gama"
}]

function test(obj) {
  return obj.every(a => a.hasOwnProperty("value"));
}

console.log(test(x))
```

**Update**

As rightfully mentioned by this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536862/check-to-see-if-all-objects-in-an-array-has-a-common-porperty/46537300#comment80028552_46536862) first.

Answer (score 0):

Here can be the simple solution for this object:

```
var x = [{
  "item": "alpha",
  "value": "red"
}, {
  "item": "beta",
  "value": "blue"
}, {
  "item": "beta",
  "value": "gama"
}];

function test(obj) {
   var keyCount = 0;

   obj.forEach(function (item, index) {
      item.hasOwnProperty('value') && ++keyCount;
   });

   return keyCount == obj.length;
}

console.log(test(x));
```